# Why does this program not fail after downloading 5 images

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I recently made a program that downloads photos of the site and adds them into a folder. For some reason when it reaches photo number 5, photos after it are corrupted.

```
import urlextractor
import time
import sys
n = input('enter id:')


url = urlextractor.id_to_url_conv(n)
maxpage = urlextractor.getLastPage(url)

print(f'This is max page==>{maxpage}')
m = int(input('Sehife sayi:'))
if m < int(maxpage):
        urlextractor.getPhotosFromFirstToN(n, m)
  
else:
        print('You have exceeded max page limit')
        time.sleep(3)
        sys.exit()
```

This is main.py

and urlextractor.py is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import sys
import time
def id_to_url_conv(id):
    return f'http://web2.anl.az:81/read/page.php?bibid={id}&pno=1'

def getLastPage(url):
    req = requests.get(url, 'html.parser')
    num = req.text.find('title="Son vÉ™rÉ™q"')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

    x = soup.find(id="last_link")
    z = str(x)
    page_number = ''
    index = z.find('pno')
    for i in range(index+4,len(z)):
        if z[i] != '"':
            page_number += z[i]
        else:
            break
    last_page_number = page_number    

    return int(page_number)
def getPhotosFromFirstToN(id1, number,):
        os.mkdir(directory)
            for i in range(z + 1, number + 1):
                try:
                    fhand = open(f'{directory}/p{i}.png', 'wb')
                    photourl = f'http://web2.anl.az:81/read/img.php?bibid={id1}&pno={i}'
                    url = requests.get(photourl).content
                    fhand.write(url)
                    fhand.close() 
                    print(f'page number {i} has been created {i/number * 100}')
                except:
                    print(f'#{i} error occured')
```

Is there problem that I could solve or better program?

Comment: Program asks for a ID of a book first: 642496 this is id.

Comment: Then amount of pages, try 15, and name of new directory to put files on.

Comment: Why not just print the exception and stacktrace on your `except`case?

Comment: What is stacktrace?

Comment: It downloads all images and no errors happen, but files after 5th one are corrupted.